# CA2201 NullReferenceException warnings

Tags: c#

I'm cleaning some C# code and I've found some CA2201 warnings. I understand the issue but I'm not sure about what kind of exception I should raise.

Take a look of this piece of code, it's the 'DoWork' Event callback of a BackgroundWorker.

```
private void DoWork(Object s, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
    var worker = s as BackgroundWorker;
    if (worker == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException();

    // DoSomeStuff();
    }
```

In this case, I think an ArgumentException may resolve the warning, but what about this one?

```
public void Foo()
    {
    var thing = MyFactory.Create(someArgs);
    if (thing == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException();

    thing.DoSomeStuff();
    }
```

In this case I can't find what kind of Exception I should raise, just because I have just a NullReferenceException. What should i do there?

Greetings.

Comment: Don't throw an exception if you are handling the case, if(worker == null) return;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521401/c-sharp-what-kind-of-exception-should-i-raise

Comment: In the second case it's not an ArgumentException, InvalidOperationException or FormatException, just the thing object is null. And I don't want to implement my own Exception if there is one which fits in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own exception class - i.e. `InstanceWasNotCreatedException` and throw instance of these. Some usefull message will be nice.

Comment: As I said, I know I can implement my custom exception. I only want to know if is there any stardand exception to use in that case instead of doing my own.